# How to fit to display footer tag with 100% width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to set my footer width 100%, but not working.

In Bootstrap by default footer and other tags are not fit to display, respectively width is not 100%. Why is that?

HTML code:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <footer class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <p><small>Copyright <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span>  This is a small footer. </small></p>

        <img src="img/fb.png" alt=""> &nbsp
        <img src="img/twitter.png" alt=""> &nbsp
        <img src="img/youtube.png" alt=""> &nbsp
        <img src="img/myspace.png" alt="">
    </footer>
```

Also I tried some solutions, but without success.

```
footer {
    padding: 2em 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;

    background-size: contain;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Also I added following code, but again without success:

```
footer{
padding: 2em 0;
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
color: #999;
text-align: center;
background-color: #2b2b2b;

min-width:100%;
}
```

Also I added on start of CSS to reset margin and padding

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Here is illustrated explanation  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGhsj.png

Comment: Note that in TWBS, we have `.row`s containing `.col-*`s. The footer in this case is given both of `row` and `col-*` classes mistakenly.

Comment: Thanks, but Sorry I don't understand you what you want to say?

Comment: If you don't want the bootstrap grid system to handle the width of the footer, simply don't give bootstrap's classes to the element. Then the footer as the other block-level elements will fill the entire space of its parent horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your footer needs to sit inside a `container-fluid` rather than a `container` element. As described in the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container):

> Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

Example: http://www.bootply.com/db004KoXCR

```css
.example {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="footer">
  <div class="container example">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        Non-fluid container Non-fluid container Non-fluid container
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid example">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        Fluid container Fluid container Fluid container
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working :/
`<div class="container-fluid">
    <footer class="row col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <p><small>Copyright <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span>  This is a small footer. </small></p>

        <img src="img/fb.png" alt=""> &nbsp
     <img src="img/twitter.png" alt=""> &nbsp
     <img src="img/youtube.png" alt=""> &nbsp
     <img src="img/myspace.png" alt="">
    </footer>
</div>`

Comment: Note that the class hierarchy for Bootstrap must start with a `container`, that must contain a `row` and inside that is where you put the `col-*` elements. Check out my example.

Comment: Sorry man i see inyou case it's working perfectly.In my case no success
`<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
         <p><small>Copyright <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span>  This is a small footer. </small></p>

        <img src="img/fb.png" alt=""> &nbsp
     <img src="img/twitter.png" alt=""> &nbsp
     <img src="img/youtube.png" alt=""> &nbsp
     <img src="img/myspace.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: You are still missing a `div` with class `row`. Remember that it must ALWAYS go `container` -> `row` -> `col`

Comment: Thank you, now working. But on start of project i made one big container and inside i putting others divs. Now in this case, for container-fluid not working if he is inside of big container, when I cut out and paste after big container thats work perfectly.
Is this semantic correctly?
I think you understand me my english is not very good !
Best regards!

Comment: In Bootastrap, `container` elements can't be nested. Just create a new one outside of the  main one.

Comment: Can you tell me about `col`-... , in this case for footer, which `col` is necessary to set. Only `col-xs-12` or all `col` (`col-lg-12 col-md-12- col-sm-12 col-xs-12`)

It's got me stumped.
Thank you so much

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation, it's pretty good http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Ok I will thanks, but can you tell me just a little about that.

Comment: You expect me to read out the documentation to you in this tiny text box?